# Automatically begin lazy loading images without waiting for user to scroll down page

Tags: html, javascript, css, jquery, user-experience

Websites will often lazy load images as the user scrolls down the page to allow the initial viewed top portion of the page to load faster.

Instead of waiting until the user decides to scroll down the page, is it possible to detect when the top images have been downloaded to the client (or accessed via cached images), and then immediately start downloading the next set of images?  If so, how?

Comment: Do you really need lazy loading? Why not just load all the images simultaneously and let the browser handle it? Otherwise, maybe you can use the `onload` function on each of the images.

Comment: @MrLister.  Want the images initially viewed by the user to display first, not those below the page or within an accordion or carousel, so the browser might not handle it correctly.  Maybe something like `<div onload="doNext()">` where the DIV contains all the images I wish to show first.  Then `function doNext()` would update the DOM for the not initially viewed section of the  page?  Will imaging caching work on this second part?

Comment: I see no reason why cached images would disrupt things. AFAIK they just trigger the onload event when they are visible, just like images loaded from the net. Of course you might always find browsers that work differently...

Answer (score 0):

[See demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x23pu/). The implementation is quite straightforward: listen to `window.onload` for the first time, to wait until the complete page has been loaded. Once it fires, load the next image and listen for its `onload` event. Repeat that, until no more images need preloading:

```
function loadNext() {
    var img = findNextImageToPreload(); 
    img.load(function () {
        loadNext();
    });
    setImgSrcOnImageSoItStartsPreloading(img);
}

$(window).load(function () {
    loadNext();
});
```

This is the basic idea only and not a working `loadNext` function. The one implemented in the jsfiddle loads one image after another. If you want to be able to load multiple images at once you need to call `loadNext` multiple times.

In any case, you need an additional check if the images is scrolled/brought into view before it has been preloaded. Obviously you’d want to start loading it immediately.

Also be aware that some browsers might avoid loading the image if it isn’t visible. Especially mobile browsers do that in some cases. You can use `deelay.me` for that. If all `loadNext` run at the same second, then you need to place the image somewhere invisible to the user, but “visible” to the browser in order to void its logic. In most cases I would recommend against tricking the browsers because the vendors put a lot of effort into making requests reasonable. Highly depends on your use case though. Hope this helps.